# Fastest means of removing comments from JSON in java?

Tags: java, json, comments, minify

Looked all around the internet for a java port of a reliable json comment stripper and minifier, but most were flawed designs (not supporting multiline comments, or comment patterns within strings).

So in my haste, I went and threw this together: https://gist.github.com/justisr/abab012af3ef399908798a687185d49a

Gave it a test on an existing json file I had, and everything came out as expected, but I'm not satisfied.
Is there really no faster/standard means of stripping comments from a json string?

Previously I was using https://github.com/getify/JSON.minify but it was slow and again, a regular // comment at the end of the file broke it, hence my desperation.

Comment: JSON format by definition cannot contain comments of any means (neither `//`, nor `/* ... */`), are you referring to the JavaScript objects?

Comment: Yes of course. Javascript comments within an otherwise legal JSON object.

Comment: I see. I have never seen libraries for normalizing JavaScript to JSON before. I guess your Gist is fine, unless you wish to have a real JavaScript parser applied that will be anyway slower than your dedicated code to wipe comments only.

Comment: I'd always presumed it to be common practice to document JSON configurations with javascript comments for the sake of  end users and then minify them out on loading. Text editors like sublime (what I use) support them by default in their JSON syntax parsing, though perhaps I've just been spoiled.

Comment: YAML takes over JSON in the world of config files :) but its true, missing support for comments (in pure standard) is the biggest downside of JSON, and it is astonishing why this format got so popular for configuration files with such a flaw.

Comment: See [JSON5](https://json5.org) for a "standard" flavor of JSON with comments. Not sure how widely it's been adopted, but support for JSON5 was recently added to IntelliJ, which is a good sign.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simplest thing would be to run your JSON through [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
public static String removeComments(String json) throws IOException {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS);
  return mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.readTree(json));
}
```

If you wanted to get fancier, you could use Jackson's streaming API to avoid buffering the document in memory, but unless your documents are large or performance is absolutely critical, that's probably overkill.

Comment: Damn me; how could I not realize there was an allow comments option for Jackson. Hiding in plain sight as they say... Thank you.